# Auto refresh table with free marker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, freemarker, dropwizard

What i am trying to do is refreshing my table on my site. I am creating the site with bootstrap and drop wizard (free marker in drop wizard). But i have no clue on how to refresh the tables content but not the whole page. Any tips are welcome.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="lightgray">
                <td><strong>Data4</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Data3</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Data2</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Data1</strong></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <div>
            <#list datas as data>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${data.id}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${data.mobile}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${data.size}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${data.sizebytes}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a data-toggle="modal"
                           title="Info" class="open-datainfo btn btn-default" href="#logInformation">
                            <i class="icon-info-sign icon-black"></i> Data information
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </#list>
            </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you know any good links i could look at that would speed up my progress?

Comment: Any javascript library (or raw js): jQuery, Angularjs, Emberjs, backbonejs.